# Gnome fallback move to workspace not working - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome-classic

I have recently switched to Ubuntu 14.04 but using the gnome fallback desktop environment. The thing that is not working for me is that when I right click on a window's top bar and then click Move to Workspace Up for example, it puts the window in that workspace but it also keeps it in the current workspace.

I've tried all options but it just wouldn't work :(

Anyone experienced the same and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.
It turns out (at least in my case) that the workspace option was turned off as part of the upgrade. All I had to do was go to System Setting, Appearance, Behaviour(tab) and turn on the 'Enable Workspaces' radio button. That restored workspace functionality to the way that I remember it before the upgrade.

I got this info from the following site:
http://www.unixmen.com/quick-tip-enable-workspaces-ubuntu-14-04-lts-desktop/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not particular about what fallback Gnome you are using, the workspaces work in Gnome (Metacity).  They do not seem to work in Gnome (Compiz).